# GCP How can we attach google armor with google NEG?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I could not find any documentation mentioning how to attach armor with NEG, the terraform syntax.
We are creating armor as Security policy. i managed to find an example connecting it with Project but could not find how to connect it to NEG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't attach a Cloud Armor policy to a NEG but to a Load Balancer backend. You can find this option in te [google_compute_backend_service](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_backend_service#security_policy). This backend also contains your NEG.

And you put this backend in a forwarding rule.